# Is there some way to arbitrarily set the active trail?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a menu as such:

- Home
- Performances
- News
- Learning
- ...

I have a content type called 'Event' and when viewing a node of the event type I want to set the 'Performances' menu item as active. How would I go about doing this?

[menu_set_active_trail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7) doesn't seem to work :s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Drupal 7.9 or later you can use the [`menu_tree_set_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7) function, e.g.

```
menu_tree_set_path('main-menu', 'performances');
```

Comment: I tried using this in [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) however this seems to be called too late to have any effect. Placing it in [`hook_init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) did work, however is this the most appropriate place to put this logic?

Comment: `hook_init()` doesn't fire for cached pages so YMMV there...better to do it in the context to which it belongs (in my opinion). So if 'performances' is a view, put it in a views hook, if it's a node a node view hook/preprocess, and so on

Comment: [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) is working great for me for my setup.

Comment: `template_preprocess_page()` works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

[Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) should do what you need (Drupal 7), it's fairly broad and contextual in scope. Once installed, go to /admin/structure/menu-position and add a new Menu Position rule. You will see there are all kinds of contexts, then theme away with Firebug and CSS (or you may not even need to depending on how your menus are already set up for active items / trails).